# Не вызывается onCreateViewHolder в PagedListAdapter-е

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, recycleview

Имеется **PagedListAdapter** :

```
class TrackedActivityAdapter constructor(diffUtilCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<TrackedActivity>) :
    PagedListAdapter<TrackedActivity, TrackedActivityAdapter.TrackedActivityHolder>(diffUtilCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrackedActivityHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ActivityItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.activity_item, parent, false)
        return TrackedActivityHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TrackedActivityHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
    }

    class TrackedActivityHolder(var binding: ActivityItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(trackedActivity: TrackedActivity) {
            binding.activity = trackedActivity
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

    }
}
```

И фрагмент в котором он создается :

```
class HistoryFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<HistoryFragmentViewBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.history_fragment_view,
            container,
            false
        )
        val historyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(HistoryViewModel::class.java)
        val adapter = TrackedActivityAdapter(TrackedActivity.DIFF_CALLBACK)
        binding.trackedActivityRv.adapter = adapter
        binding.trackedActivityRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(binding.root.context)
        historyViewModel.getTrackedActivities().observe(this,
            Observer<PagedList<TrackedActivity>> { t ->
                adapter.submitList(t)
            })
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

После того как вызывается метод adapter.submitList(t) 
Ничего не происходит, и методы onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder не вызываются, подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть причина, никак не могу понять(

Сам проект https://github.com/flagmen/test

Comment: t - это List<TrackedActivity>

Comment: нашёл пример https://github.com/tutsplus/android-architecture-components-using-the-paging-library-with-room/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/chikeandroid/pagingtutsplus/MainActivity.kt и тут всё работает без adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() или adapter.invalidate() , правда отличие в том что там используется Activity для RecycleView

Comment: Я имел ввиду что приходит. Например выведите в логи: Log.e(localClassName, "t = $t")

Comment: приходит список с одним элементом

Comment: Вы его в логах видели или так предполагаете что он должен прийти? historyViewModel.getTrackedActivities().observe(this,
            Observer<PagedList<TrackedActivity>> { t ->
                Log.e(localClassName, "t = $t")  adapter.submitList(t) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }) этот кусок кода работает в асинхронном режиме, сделайте как указано выше. я предполагаю или туда ничего не приходит или он у вас вообще не вызывается

Comment: Добавил лог и notify: E/TAG: t = [TrackedActivity(id=, activityName=Qwe, startDate=, startTime=, duration=1, tags=[])] у t тип - ContiguousPagedList , в холдер все равно не заходит

Comment: Стало интересно. Есть какой-то открытый Логин и Пароль в приложении?

Comment: есть, но он хранится в SharedPrefernces , проще выпилить авторизацию , в PositionalDatasource вовзращать всегда один элемент, если хотите проверить

Comment: Ничего интересного( Только час зря потратил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не путайте ConstraintLayout с LinearLayout! Если используете Linear, используйте match_parent, а не 0dp.

history_fragment_view.xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/tracked_activity_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/activity_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. Проект написан добротно, но вот с именованием класов, а соответственно и объектов местами очень плохо и путанно. Activity - это Activity, а не вот это вот: TrackedActivity - делает не понятно что, так ещё и является описанием сущности.

P.S.S Не прячьте проект и не удаляйте его, кому нужно будет понять принципы работы с LiveData, Pagination(пагинация списков), Dagger2, "Room", с использованием рекомендуемых гуглом принципов [проектирования](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) из [JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)

Comment: Спасибо за совет) Просто это первый проект на Android и пишется в сжатые сроки, и так вышло что TrackedActivity это лучшее что было для описание сущности

Comment: Да действительно помогло , спасибо огромное, а почему так произошло что из-за размера View не вызывался Holder ? проблема в том что изначально ConstrainLayout был и я забыл поменять (

Comment: @flagmen, я и сам неоднократно стыкался со схожей проблемой. В начале я ошибся предположив что это у ViewPager2 на самом же дели вы делали пагинацию списков. Список реализован на основе RecyclerView, у которого есть множество оптимизаций для уменьшения потребления ресурсов, одна из таких оптимизаций это: не создавать элементы если их не будет видно, а так как RecyclerView не видно совсем, то он и вовсе не создаёт элементы списка. Если вы собираетесь после учёбы заниматься разработкой ПО, почитайте о библиотеках, там много интересного и вкусного)))